# Mensagem na pagina JSP Servlet

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Estou desenvolvendo um login em JSP e Servlet em que faz a validação dos campos se estão preenchidos e certos mas ao redirecionar para pagina de login ele não apresenta a mensagem de Por favor preencha os campos de login ou senha ou Login ou senha incorretos.

Pagina JSP

```
 <div class="cadastrado">
                <h2 id="AcesseConta"><span class="fa fa-user"> Já sou Cadastrado</span></h2>


                    <p  style="color:red;" align="center"><c:out value="${vazio}"/></p>



                <c:if test="${!empty incorretos}">
                    <p  style="color:red;" align="center">${param.incorretos}</p><br/>
                </c:if> 


                <form action="Login" method="POST"  >

                      <div class="componentes_login">Login:<input type="text" id="login" name="login" ></div><br/>
                    <div class="componentes_login"> Senha:<input type="password" id="senha" name="senha" ></div><br/>

                    <div class="componentes_login"><button type="submit" class="btn_login">Entrar</button>  <button type="submit" onclick="" class="btn_login" >Esqueceu a Senha?</button> </div>
                    <div class="margin_baixo"></div>

                </form>
            </div>
```

Servlet

```
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

     String vazio="Por favor preencha os campos de login ou senha"; 
   String incorretos="Login ou senha incorretos"; 

     String login = request.getParameter("login");
      String senha = request.getParameter("senha");

        Cliente cli= new Cliente();
           LoginDAO login2= new  LoginDAO();

       Cliente login_validacao=login2.validacaoLogin(login,senha);

 if(login_validacao.getLogin()==null && login_validacao.getSenha()==null){
request.setAttribute("vazio",vazio);

 RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");

 rd.forward(request, response);

  }
 else if(login_validacao.getLogin().equals(request.getParameter("login")) & login_validacao.getSenha().equals((request.getParameter("senha")))){

  HttpSession session=request.getSession();

  String nome= (String) login_validacao.getNome();

  session.setAttribute("nome",nome);

  request.setAttribute("nome",session.getAttribute(nome));


  RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
  rd.forward(request, response);
  }

  else{

 request.setAttribute("incorreto", incorretos); 

 RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
 rd.forward(request, response);

  }
}
```

Comment: tenta usar `requestScope.incorretos` em ambos os campos no jsp

Comment: não funcionou Bruno Morales